# What's the cleanest and most efficient way to pass two stereo images to a loss function in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

First off, why am I using Keras? I'm trying to stay as high level as possible, which doesn't mean I'm scared of low-level Tensorflow; I just want to see how far I can go while keeping my code as simple and readable as possible.

I need my Keras model (custom-built using the Keras functional API) to read the left image from a stereo pair and minimize a loss function that needs to access both the right and left images. I want to store the data in a `tf.data.Dataset`.

What I tried:

1. Reading the dataset as `(left image, right image)`, i.e. as tensors with shape `((W, H, 3), (W, H, 3))`, then use function closure: define a `keras_loss(left_images)` that returns a `loss(y_true, y_pred)`, with `y_true` being a `tf.Tensor` that holds the right image. The problem with this approach is that `left_images` is a `tf.data.Dataset` and Tensorflow complains (rightly so) that I'm trying to operate on a dataset instead of a tensor.
2. Reading the dataset as `(left image, (left image, right image))`, which should make `y_true` a `tf.Tensor` with shape `((W, H, 3), (W, H, 3))` that holds both the right and left images. The problem with this approach is that it...does not work and raises the following error:

   ```
   ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays 
   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. 
   Expected to see 1 array(s), for inputs ['tf_op_layer_resize/ResizeBilinear'] 
   but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [<tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' 
   shape=(None, 512, 256, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'args_2:0' 
   shape=(None, 512, 256, 3) dtype=float32>]...
   ```

So, is there anything I did not consider? I read the documentation and found nothing about what gets considered as `y_pred` and what as `y_true`, nor about how to convert a dataset into a tensor smartly and without loading it all in memory.

My model is designed as such:

```
 def my_model(input_shape):
     width = input_shape[0]
     height = input_shape[1]
     inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
     # < a few more layers >
     outputs = tf.image.resize(tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.slice(disp6, [0, 0, 0, 0], [-1, -1, -1, 2])), tf.Variable([width, height]))
     model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
     return model
```

And my dataset is built as such (in case 2, while in case 1 only the function `read_stereo_pair_from_line()` changes):

```
def read_img_from_file(file_name):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_name)
    # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    # resize the image to the desired size.
    return tf.image.resize(img, [args.input_width, args.input_height])


def read_stereo_pair_from_line(line):
    split_line = tf.strings.split(line, ' ')
    return read_img_from_file(split_line[0]), (read_img_from_file(split_line[0]), read_img_from_file(split_line[1]))

# Dataset loading
list_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset('test/files.txt')
images_ds = list_ds.map(lambda x: read_stereo_pair_from_line(x))
images_ds = images_ds.batch(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just needed to read the dataset as `(left image, [left image, right image])` instead of `(left image, (left image, right image))` i.e. make the second item a list and not a tuple. I can then access the images as `input_r = y_true[:, 1, :, :]` and `input_l = y_true[:, 0, :, :]`